# How to make gwt material table

Tags: gwt, uibinder, gwtp

I got gwt material table from github https://github.com/GwtMaterialDesign/gwt-material-table

But i am not getting any jar of it to inherit. So if any one who got the jar please reply me.

If jar is not there then what we have to do either using the class from git or any other way.

After having research on it i have try to make plugin by taking all file from git but $this() is creating a problem.

I can't able figure out what is use of $this() in gwt. I have also include the file gwt material query but then also the  method $this() is undefined for the type AbstractDataTable error is comming.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to add this to your pom.xml

```
<!-- For GWT Material JQuery -->
<dependency>
   <groupId>com.github.gwtmaterialdesign</groupId>
   <artifactId>gwt-material-jquery</artifactId>
   <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
</dependency>

<!-- For GWT Material Table -->
<dependency>
   <groupId>com.github.gwtmaterialdesign</groupId>
   <artifactId>gwt-material-table</artifactId>
   <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure whether I understand your problem correctly. If it's about resolving dependency, you should be able simply to get it from Maven. As you see from Github, this is a Snapshot. It means you need to add proper repository to your pom.xml file. Please see the section "repositories" and details related to "snapshots-repo" provided there: https://github.com/GwtMaterialDesign/gwt-material-table/blob/master/pom.xml .

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.github.gwtmaterialdesign</groupId>
    <artifactId>gwt-material-table</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
</dependency>
```

Hope you'll find it helpful.

Comment: I have inherited all the dependencies in gwt p but problem is that i don't know about $this(). And $this() does not found error come .